# EL variable resolution in JSF: is there a way to control when it happens?

Tags: jsf, el, composite-component

I often face the following problem. I have a JSF application and a facelet where I write EL expressions, like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.foo}">
```

As long as `myBean`, as a variable, has a life long enough, there's no problem to evaluate `myBean.foo` at any given time, but if `myBean`  is a variable that references some bean within a short period of time, when `myBean.foo` is evaluated it might be too late, so that JSF complains that `myBean` resolves to `null`. This is something well-known, but the problem is that it is not clear to me what to expect in different situations.

Concrete example n. 1: if you try the following with PrimeFaces OrderList:

```
<p:orderList value="#{bean.myValue}" var="item">
  <p:column>
    <p:commandLink action="#{bean.doSomething(item)}" />
  </p:column>
</p:orderList>`
```

This is not going to work, because when `doSomething` is called, the `item` variable is no longer defined (although the object it references is still alive) and hence it's resolved to `null`. It's a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2713). However the same pattern works fine with `<p:dataTable>`, for instance. Anyway, I'm not interested right now in this specific problem, I just want to explain my doubt.

Concrete example n. 2: I have written a composite component with a backing bean. The backing bean extends `UINamingContainer` and uses its `StateHelper` to retain a model object. This composite allows to write child tags and I would like to write something like this:

```
<myns:myCc var="myVar">
  <h:inputText value="#{myVar.foo}" />
</myns>
```

With "myVar" I want to give a name to the model object. To make this work, I tried to store the model object in the request map at the beginning of `encodeChildren` method and remove it afterwards: this works for rendering, but if I then process the input with a commandButton action, it does not work because when the action gets executed it says that `myVar` can't be resolved: in other words, it tries to resolve the entire expression too late. I then tried to "permanently" save the model object in the view scope map, but it doens't work either. However, if I change this to:

(assuming `modelObject` is the property field in the backing bean that stores my model object)
it works. So, it is not a problem in my model, but in the way I try to make the model object available to EL expressions for child tags.

Concrete example n. 3: I often use the `<ui:param>` tag to give beans a shorter name and to ease templating. For instance:

```
<ui:param name="bean" value="#{longNamedAndPageSpecificBean}" />
```

So that, in the remainder of the page I can just use `#{bean.foo}` instead of `#{longNamedAndPageSpecificBean.foo}`. This works fine even for actions passed to command buttons. However, if I pass a method expression like `#{bean.myActionMethod}` to a composite component attribute declared with `method-signature`, when this method expression is actually invoked I receive an error that `bean` resolves to `null`... The reason why it works in one case (with commandButton actions) and not in the other (with actions used by the composite component) is a big source of confusion for me.

I would appreciate if someone can help me to understand better this JSF aspect and suggest better approaches/workarounds with the aforementioned concrete examples.

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks too large, but i could say that, during the build time only Session and request scoped values are avaiaible.

The same thing is true for the Execution phase.

Only the render phase should ensure the avaibility of temporal vars "myVar".

The best way to understand what its realy hapening is to debug because its depends on the component implementation

Comment: And what about the case where the component implementation is mine (case 2)?
Anyway, it's exactly this uncertainty (the need to debug to understand things) that is mining JSF productivity in many cases. Things are not working in a "linear" way, because "it depends". Unless, of course, there's a rule of thumb that explains the different behaviours, and this is the heart of the question.